# Convert ALTIUM file to Autodesk EAGLE: what is the most recent procedure?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, eaglecad, layout

I would like to convert following Altium file to EAGLE:
https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32wlex.html#cad-resources

To do so I have opened the file in Altium and exported it to P-CAD ASCII according to some forum posts on the Autodesk forum:
https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/eagle-forum/importing-files-from-altium-designer-to-eagle/td-p/6827258

I could import it in Autodesk EAGLE but the design is broken at many pads:
[image: EAGLE 1 conversion]
[image: ALTIUM 1 original]
[image: EAGLE 2 conversion]
[image: ALTIUM 2 original]

I've also observed a couple of errors when importing the Altium-generated file like 'Couldn't place smd4 on padXX'.

My questions are:
What are the most recent or best ways to import Altium files in EAGLE?

Comment: You are at the mercy of the importer, if it doesn't do what you want it to then you'll have to correct the mistakes. You could always try importing the gerbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing the Gerber files, as @Voltage Spike suggested works nicely in Autodesk EAGLE version 9.x.x:
[Can you load Gerber files back into a PCB layout designer such as Eagle?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/233786/can-you-load-gerber-files-back-into-a-pcb-layout-designer-such-as-eagle)

You just need to be aware of the layer assignments, which are provided by Altium:
https://www.nexpcb.com/blog/what-is-a-gerber-file-and-how-to-i-get-one